# Syntax Highlighting for Column-based Language

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I am working with files that have a specific character layout, i.e.

```
bytes 1-10    bytes11-20
FirstName     LastName
FirstName     LastName
```

Is there anyway to specify a language that highlights or changes background based on column position?

Comment: How many "columns" are there?

Comment: Each line is 1000 characters long. Each column is anywhere from 1 to 50 characters long. I don't know the exact column count yet.I would have to manually count them in the MASSIVE standards document.

Comment: OK, I was just checking that it was more than two. Notepad++ has a feature that can highlight the first *n* characters differently, but I don't think there is any way to define more than one position.

Comment: That's too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Possible in SynWrite app. Lexer there can have regex.

- For 1st rule set `^\S{50}` regex.
- For 2nd rule set similar regex using "Positive look ahead assertion". E.g. assertion `(?<=www)test` is "test" after "www".